# Hatcher 2.1.19 exercise

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

**Problem**: Compute the homology groups of the subspace of $I\times I$ consisting of the four boundary edges and the points having first co-ordinate rational number.

I have solved this problem but want to know other ways to solve this problem.

**My solution** :

Let $A=$ the top boundary edge and $B=$ the bottom boundary edge. $C=$the given subspace. Then $(C,A)$ and $(C/A,B)$ are good pairs. Now $(C/A)/B$ is suspension of $I\cap \mathbb Q$. And we know $\tilde H_n(X)=\tilde H_{n+1}(SX)$ and we are done.

(Mainly I want to know other solution because to solve 2.1.19 I'm using 2.1.20.)